# Option for 360 degree movie embedded in Open Source GIS software?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, geoserver, grass-gis, mapguide

Is there any Open Source GIS software available to embed 360 degree movies with the map?

For a COTS example, there is the [Active Link Vision (ALV) extension for ArcGIS](http://www.iwane.com/en/alvforarcgis_overview.php) from IWANE.

Comment: pan0? http://pan0.net/map.php?set_accept=1&perm=1#lat=19.973348786110602&lng=-11.25&zoom=2 pan0 - open-source, Flash 9 based panorama player